# How do I refer to a class inside of an event listener made inside the same class?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
class TestClass {
    constructor(word) {
        this.word = word;
        window.addEventListener("keypress", this.logCharCodeAndWord);
        window.addEventListener("click", this.logWord)
    }
    logCharCodeAndWord(e) {
        console.log(e.charCode);
        console.log(this.word)
    }
    logWord() {
        console.log(this.word)
    }
}

var testObject = new TestClass("banana");
```

I don't even know how to ask this question, but here's my problem...

```
console.log(this.word)
```

This logs "undefined" to the console, because `this` refers to `window` instead of the TestClass. I want `this.word` to refer to "banana", and I would like to be able to use the `e.charCode` part at the same time.

How would I do that?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried searching on my own but couldn't find a single relevant link anywhere. After all, I didn't know the technical terms to search for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either pass in the `this` of your class object:

```
window.addEventListener("click", this.logWord.bind(this))
```

Or you can use an arrow-function:

```
window.addEventListener("click", () => this.logWord())
```

Comment: This is one of the most commonly-asked duplicate questions. Futher answers aren't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass `this` to your event listeners.

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", e => this.logCharCodeAndWord(e, this));
window.addEventListener("click", () => this.logWord(this));
```

```js
class TestClass {
    constructor(word) {
        this.word = word;
        window.addEventListener("keypress", e => this.logCharCodeAndWord(e, this));
        window.addEventListener("click", () => this.logWord(this));
    }
    logCharCodeAndWord(e, self) {
        console.log(e.charCode);
        console.log(self.word)
    }
    logWord(self) {
        console.log(self.word)
    }
}

var testObject = new TestClass("banana");
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the this if you use an arrow function.

Comment: This is one of the most commonly-asked duplicate questions. Futher answers aren't useful. (And as Christian points out, the above is a bit confused, applying two separate fixes.)

Comment: Thanks @Christian for pointing out